# bash: git pull has modification condition

Tags: git, bash, git-pull

I want to make a bash script that will run a git pull and run some other command to update the project's data / cache.

I would like to run those commands only if the git pull command had updated the project (new commits were retrieved).

Something like that would be nice:

```
#!/bin/bash

git pull
if *git pull brought new commits*; then
    # run update cache commands
fi
```

A grep filter on git pull output could do the trick, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using [git hooks](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) here

Comment: Specifically, a `post-merge` hook would be run whenever any new commits were pulled in.

Comment: Alternatively or additionally use something (like make) that only takes action when its inputs have changed.

Comment: But be careful, a `post-merge` hook won't be executed if you use `git pull --rebase`. (@TomFenech FYI)

Comment: @TomFenech I'm looking for something external to git. In most case, I will pull without running the script.